# Installation error invalid magic number

Tags: boot

I don't have pendrive or CD so I used my phone to make bootable file using app name Drivedroid. I'm trying to install Ubuntu but I get this error:

[image: boot error]

First, I thought the file have some problem so I downloaded it again but the error remain same . So it tried Kali Linux and it boot very simply I also tried windows 10 and even it work also but for some reason Ubuntu didn't.
Please help to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Please provide the exact version of the Ubuntu ISO you used.